# GetScreenOrientation Delphi XE5 and Android

Tags: android, delphi, orientation

i am using rad studio xe5 and i need to return the current screen orientation to the text property of a label on my form.

how can i get the value of TScreenOrientation();

thank you amit

Comment: I haven't got a copy of XE5 to hand, but in the absence of a form property, and the form is maximised, a simple check of Portrait := (Height > Width) would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
uses
  FMX.Platform;
....
var
  ScreenService: IFMXScreenService;
....
ScreenService := TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXScreenService) 
  as IFMXScreenService;
Orientation := ScreenService.GetScreenOrientation;
```